In my GitLab pipeline, how can I trigger a notification job for a failing job but still let the remaining jobs continue after that?
How the pipeline should work
I have the following jobs in my GitLab pipeline:
Job_A:
   script: # script doing things
   retry:
      max: 2

Job_B:
   script: # script doing things
   retry:
      max: 2

Job_C:
   script: # script doing things
   retry:
      max: 2

Each job has a notifying job that looks like this:
notify_job_A_failure:
   script: # script sending alert to MS Teams
   when: on_failure
   needs:
      - Job_A
   allow_failure: true

The problem is, if e.g. Job_A fails, the notifying job is triggered BUT the pipeline stops after that and Job_B and Job_C don't run. Is there a solution to this case?
I tried adding 'allow_failure: true' to the jobs so the pipeline can continue, but that led to the notifying jobs not being triggered.

The default when for a job is on_success.  This means that a job only runs if the previous stage or needed job completed successfully.  Since you've changed that for each "notifier" job those still run on a failed job.  However, you haven't done that for jobs B and C.  You could change when those jobs run to always so they run regardless of what happens with previous jobs.  I'm also assuming that those jobs are in different stages as they would run at the same time as job A if they were in the same stage.  If you don't need jobs B and C to run after job A you could also put them in the same stage for it to work.  But if you're relying on job A completing before job B and job B completing before job C, just change the when key to always.
Job_A:
   script: # script doing things
   retry:
      max: 2

Job_B:
   when: always
   script: # script doing things
   retry:
      max: 2

Job_C:
   script: # script doing things
   when: always
   retry:
      max: 2

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when
